# Как задать правильную высоту для outline ссылки-картинки?

Tags: html, css

Cитуация следующая:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="#">
</a>
```

У картинки max-width: 100%, чтобы картинка могла масштабироваться. Ссылка получается адекватной ширины (ширины картинки), но высоты 20px, независимо от размеров изображения. Само изображение остаётся 100% кликабельным, ссылка срабатывает и за пределами этой высоты, но например в хроме outline после клика по такой картинке тоже обладает высотой 20px.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно сделать outline совпадающим с картинкой по размеру? Убивать outline не хотелось бы.

Comment: Что-то такое `a {display: inline-block;}` ?

Comment: Это приводит к тому что он залезает под картинку и остаётся только один его край, если картинка прижата к границам блока. Но уже лучше, чем дефолтное поведение.

Comment: поэкспериментируйте с внешним/внутренним отступами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img src=//placehold.it/350x150>
</a>
```